# Conjugate of a complex number in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab

In order to convert a Matlab code to C, I want to write it in a similar way to C first then its translation would become trivial.
I faced a problem with this line:

```
A = E*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];
```

Where E is (9x4) real matrix and SOLS is (3x10) complex matrix. A should be a 9x10 complex matrix.

I translated this line as follows:

```
for i=1:9
  for j=1:10
    A(i,j)=E(i,1)*conj(SOLS(j,1))+E(i,2)*conj(SOLS(j,2))+E(i,3)*conj(SOLS(j,3))+ E(i,4);
  end
end
```

I got the same result. When I replaced  `conj(X)` by `real(X)-i*imag(X)`for example:

```
conj(SOLS(j,1))  by `real(SOLS(j,1))-imag(SOLS(j,1))*i`,
```

I got a wrong result and I don't understand why.

I'm doing this because in the C code, every complex number is represented by a struct with variable.re the real part and variable.im the imaginary part.

```
typedef struct COMPLEX{
    float re;
    float im;
}Complex;
```

I want to write a very similar matlab code to C to manipulate variables easily in C with getting a similar result with Matlab.

How to correct this please?

Comment: How is your result wrong? Also, the matrix dimensions in `A = E*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];` don't agree. Is the `'` operator supposed to be there?

Comment: I want to translate the matlab code to C. Why in the nested loops when I replace conj(X) by (real(X)-imag(X)*i) I get a different result from when I just write conj(X)?

Comment: The previous question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236660/conjugate-of-a-complex-number-in-matlab/29236947#29236947

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `i` both as a looping index and `sqrt(-1)`.
If you want to replace `conj(SOLS(j,1))` use instead

```
 real(SOLS(j,1))-imag(SOLS(j,1))*1i
```

Comment: Nice catch. If I'm not mistaken, `j` should be the column index `SOLS` as well, rather than the row index. I think the OP made an error in their code.

Comment: @eigenchris That's actually not an error if I understand what the OP wants to do, it's a column index because the transpose operation is applied

Comment: I see the OP used the `'` operator in `A = E*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];`, but that makes the indeces disagree if `SOLS` is 3 by 10, so I'm not totally sure what's going on there. If `E` is 9 by 4, shouldn't `SOLS` with the extra row by 4 by 10? And therefore `j` should loop over the columns? Either way, I think you caught the main problem. Maybe there's something I'm just not seeing.

Comment: @eigenchris you're right, SOLS is 10x3 and SOLS' is 3x10, the OP made a mistake there...

Comment: Yes, In fact SOLS is a (10x3) and SOLS' is a (3x10)